# ApexCharts Grouped Stacked Chart: Group legend labels

Tags: javascript, charts, legend, apexcharts

I'm using ApexCharts to generate some charts and the "new" **grouped stacked column charts** comes in handy for some of them.

Now I was wondering, if it was already possible to also group the **legend labels** for a better overview, because when there are multiple series in multiple groups, the current legend becomes pretty unreadable.

I attached an example of the current legend and a proposed design below:
[image: current]

[image: grouped]

If there is no option for this new chart to format the legend in a certain way, I will post it on the Github too.